# Why doesn't this code take stdin and give output fot tc=1?

Tags: c++, while-loop, gets

Wrote the following code to take input and display that output but it doesnt works when I give tc to 1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int tc,n;
    char ch[1000];
    cin >>tc;
    while(tc--){

    gets(ch);
    puts(ch);
}}
```

Comment: Because `gets` is unsafe, prefer `fgets` or avoid it altogether and stick with `cin` or `getline`.

Comment: Are you trying to write C or C++? In what way doesn't it work? In any case, don't use `gets`, which makes it impossible to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there's a newline left in the stream which isn't consumed by `std::cin`. It's consumed by `gets` but discarded. It's a simple fix, include `<limits>` and put this after `cin`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

It's not wise to carelessly mix C and C++ code. You are already using `std::cin`, stick with it, and consider using `std::getline`. Keep in mind you'll run into the same issue if you try to mix `std::cin` and `std::getline`. It's recommended that you stick with one or the other.

**Note**: `gets` is deprecated. It's removed in C11 and C++14. Use `fgets` instead.